# How to use $.each method for an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, vtl

```
function calcTotalScore(){
    var arr = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
    $.each(arr, function(n,val){
        calcTotal(val);
    });
}

calcTotal(value){
// sample code
}
```

I am using the above function `calcTotalScore()` in Velocity Template Language(VTL), but it says:

```
Encountered "," Was expecting one of:
   <EOF> 
    "(" ...
   <RPAREN> ...
   <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ...
   <SET_DIRECTIVE> ...
   "##" ...
   "\\\\" ...
   "\\" ...
   <TEXT> ...
   "*#" ...
   "*#" ...
   <STRING_LITERAL> ...
   <IF_DIRECTIVE> ...
   <STOP_DIRECTIVE> ...
   <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
   <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
   <WORD> ...
   <BRACKETED_WORD> ...
   <IDENTIFIER> ...
   <DOT> ...
   "{" ...
   "}" ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VTL is interpreting jQuery's `$` as the start of a variable. It then complains because a variable name cannot start with a dot.

You have two options:

1. Escape the dollar with a backslash, eg. `\$`
2. Use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

see answer of a'r :D

---

You're just missing a "function" in front of calcTotal ;)

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gabel/7SvUY/1/

```
function calcTotalScore(){
    var arr = Array("A","B","C","D","E","F");
    $.each(arr, function(n,val){
        calcTotal(val);
    });
}

function calcTotal(value){
// sample code
    alert(value);
}

calcTotalScore();
```

Comment: Then it seems to be a Problem of VTL like a'r mentioned already. Did you tried to replace the " with '  ? I have no idea about VTL and wrote this answer before the additional information was added..

Comment: It just seem to be exactly the problem a'r mentioned ... see: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/ecd581b0fb548837?pli=1

Comment: yes its the problem what ar has mentioned...Thanks :), its working :)